# Why is phpinfo output different from php -i output?

Tags: linux, php, xdebug

I try to use xdebug with php 7.2.5 and netbeans but I always get "Waiting for Connection"

So I compared the settings showed in phpinfo and `php -i | grep xdebug`.

I noticed that the settings are different, e.g. phpinfo outputs `xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.40.161` while `php -i | grep xdebug.remote_host` shows `localhost`.

What is going on?